# NoMethodError in UserCrud#new while trying to create new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I am running into problems while trying to new record its showing an error message which error is not present in my code-
THe error message-

```
undefined method `user_cruds_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f403e3162f0>:0x00007f403e3527a0>
Did you mean?  user_crud_path
Extracted source (around line #8):       
  <h2>Create User</h2>

  <%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>

    <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>


Rails.root: /home/ayan/Desktop/ror/q

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/user_crud/new.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_user_crud_new_html_erb___1837862909000615994_69956949154020'
Request
Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
_csrf_token: "DChk63/c8Jl1+JamtZiB03rFYMC/kybhyZr0/JixXDo="
flash: {"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"UserCrud updated successfully."}}
session_id: "aa128a12236d1d8d94061ed5de21d7f1"
```

Which is surprisingly some other request message , but the intended method call with url path helper **"user_cruds_path"** is not present-Its already corrected.
I have already restarted the server but same problem

> Here is my controller class-

```
class UserCrudController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
    @users = UserCrud.new(users_params)
    #@users=UserCrud.new(:name=>"Ayan",:email=>"ac@gmail.com")
    # Save the object
    if @users.save
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
      flash[:notice] = "UserCrud created successfully."
      redirect_to("/user_crud/index/")
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end
  def new
    @users = UserCrud.new({:name => 'Default',:email=>'deault@domain.ext'})
  end
```

> My view for new Record creation:(new.html.erb)

```
<% @page_title = "New User" %>

<%= link_to("<< Back to List", "/user_crud/", :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="users new">
  <h2>Create User</h2>

  <%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>

    <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= f.submit("Create User") %>
    </div>



  <% end %>
</div>
```

**routees.rb**

```
      resources :user_crud do
    member do
      get :delete
    end
  end
```

Its aweird to see the error message referring to a path name that is not present at all-
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the url of the page this form is showing on when producing this error?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/user_crud/new

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the form, you are not specifying the correct path. When not setting this option, Rails will look for the "default path", which in this case is `user_cruds_path`

Comment: where and how should I add that ,I am a complete beginner in rails, modified code will be very helpful

Comment: How are your routes.rb?

Comment: added routes content

Comment: Try something like, `form_for(@users, url: users_crud_path)`

Comment: Now it gives -- No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user_crud"}, missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Its working with url:"/user_crud/" but what is the url helper for that?

Comment: My mistake, try `user_crud_path`, Rails provides the paths to you, giving a string param is not a good pratice at all.

the command rails routes will show you all your application routes

Answer (score 0):

form_for(@users, url: "/user_crud/") works , but it would be great if anyone suggests what is the suitable url helper `"/user_crud/"`

Edit:

I got it from Marcelo's Comment and found the routes by command `rails routes`
And found the url helper to be  `user_crud_index_url` for `"/user_crud/"`

So the final answer is:

```
form_for(@users,url: user_crud_index_url)
```